# I have MVC Error Parser Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

first time use MVC and i want to change the position and want to change the logo. after this i write the @using

the error is Parser Error what happened ?

```cs
@using Angga.Models 
@model LoginViewModel 
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Log in"; }


<div class="col-sm-4">

</div>


<div class="col-sm-4">
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"})) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <div class="page animsition vertical-align text-center" data-animsition-in="fade-in" data-animsition-out="fade-out" style="animation-duration: 800ms; opacity: 1;">
    <div class="page-content vertical-align-middle">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="brand">
            <img class="brand-img" src="~/image/logo-blue.png" alt="..." />
            <h2 class="brand-text font-size-18">MYLOYALTY</h2>
          </div>
          <form method="post" action="customer_search.php" autocomplete="off">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
            <div class="form-group form-material floating">
              <!-- Untuk Email-->

              <!-- <label class="floating-label">Email</label> -->
              <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

              </div>

              @*
              <input style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" />*@
            </div>
            <!-- Untuk Password-->
            <div class="form-group form-material floating">
              @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password) @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new {@class= "form-control"}) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger"}) @*

              <input style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />*@

            </div>
            <div class="form-group clearfix">
              <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-inline checkbox-primary checkbox-lg pull-left">
                <input type="checkbox" id="inputCheckbox" name="remember" />
                <label for="inputCheckbox">Remember me</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button style="" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(" About ")'">Sign in</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      }
      <footer class="page-copyright page-copyright-inverse">
        <p>© 2016. All RIGHT RESERVED.</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-4">

</div>



@section Scripts { @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") }
```

and this my code :D, the error is Parser Error

The Error is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61N67.png)

Comment: What error. And show the other code (what you have shown will not generate an error on its own)

Comment: Again. What are the details of the error.

Comment: the detail error is when i using @using(at the top), error the @using that how can i solve it ?

Comment: For the 3rd time. What are the **details** of the error!

Comment: oh see the pitcure i have upload it, the error that is

Comment: You need to include the error details in the question (not an image of it). And the error message is self explanatory. Your code is so badly formatted that we cannot wade through it, but you have a `</div>` with out a starting `<div>` - just after your commented section of code. And you have nested forms which is invalid html and will not work anyway.

Comment: is Done thanks you, yah i first time use this MVC so my code cant good to read it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this arise for your nested `form`

because you already introduce a form in html div

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"})) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  ........
```

and you try to introduce another `form` in the same form

```
 <form method="post" action="customer_search.php" autocomplete="off">
  ......
```